# Java Generics class and constructor

Tags: java, android, generics, constructor

I want to create the parent class for doing the GetInstance. But I always got crash.
`mInstance = new Instance<>();` always crash this line

```
public class Instance<T> {

    public Instance<T> mInstance;

    public Instance<T> GetInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public <T> Instance() {
        mInstance = new Instance<>();
    }
}
```

```
public class Timer extends Instance<Timer> {

}
```

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.familyfit.google.pushups.global.Instance.(Instance.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.fami

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: posed error.....

Comment: do you want Instance to be singleton?

Comment: yes................

Comment: You shouldnt be calling your constructor inside the constructor. Use a static method instead if you need a singleton

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong

In your constructor, you're calling itself recursively hence stackoverflow.

Either move the initialization of `mInstance` to outside the class or make it static.

Try this:

```
public static class Instance<T> {

    private static final Instance<?> mInstance = new Instance<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Instance<T> GetInstance() {
        // Make generic static instance. 
        // Strategy used similar to Collections.emptyList() implementation
        return (Instance<T>) mInstance;
    }

    private Instance() {

    }
}
```

Comment: To people who downvotes: If you want to downvote, leave a comment. Don't downvote simply because you don't understand java.

Comment: i feel the same.

Comment: A bad day for me haha

Answer (score 2):

This is how IntelliJ writes a Singleton using his wizard.

```
public final class Singleton{

private static final Singleton ourInstance = new Singleton();

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

/**
 * Private constructor
 */
private Singleton() {}
}
```

In this way, a singleton gets created only one time. Notice the private constructor, which does not allows you to create more instances, and the `static final` instance which has only one object of this class. At least, the `public static Singleton getInstance` method returns you the instance. Remember that for some case you would declare other methods of the singleton class as `synchronized`, but this is dependent to the business logic of your class.

Edit: as another user suggested, it is better to mark as final the class to prevent unwanted modification to the singleton logic.

Comment: would recommend to make the class `final` aswell, to prevent the creation of instances by subclassing

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 slight errors, which lead to, your singleton class not working. Firstly, your `mInstance` is not a static field of the class, which means that every instance of class `Instance` (badly choosen name TBH, use something more specific) will have it's own `mInstance` defeating the purpose of the whole, one single instance.

Secondly you have a generic class, which sadly doesn't work so well in a singleton context. Because when you always only have one instance, it doesn't make sense to introduce generics. because then you just could hardcode the generic variable `T` with `String` instead, or the type you're using.

To overcome those problems, you need to change your class as following:

```
public final class Instance {

     private static Instance mInstance;

     public static Instance getInstance(){
         if(mInstance == null){
             mInstance = new Instance();
         }
         return mInstance;
     }

     private Instance(){
         // your initialization logic
     }
}
```

I also made some normal decisions, e.g. making the class `final`, to not let a second instance *pop up*, e.g by subclassing. Then also i made the constructor and the `mInstnace` field `private`. To prevent again, unwanted changes on the class itself, and not letting the user allow to create more than one instance.

Comment: `mInstance == null` will raise condition when multiple thread try to access this static function

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn you're completly right, but this only makes sense *when* you have multiple threads, introducing a layer of synchronisation can be an overhead which may not even be used